# sql:test condition on counter

Tags: sql

I want to make a condition test during the last 3 days. The result expected is a list of only customers who math the condition. The condition is having : diffsucces>=3 during the last 3 days. I use the following query but it is not working because the condition is applied only the last day.

```
select CollectionTime,DeviceName,RessourceNameMac,diffsucces
from CmSuccess
where CollectionTime >  current_date - interval '3' day and  RessourceNameMac NOT LIKE "%00%"
group by RessourceNameMac
having (diffsucces)>=3;
```

below the sample on picture :
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z66J6.png)

With the query, ihave "EMA" and "STB" instead of "EMA"

sample 
dates;RessourceNameMac;diffsucces
17/02/2017;STB;2
17/02/2017;EMA;6
18/02/2017;EMA;10
18/02/2017;STB;1
19/02/2017;STB;4
19/02/2017;EMA;5
20/02/2017;STB;5
20/02/2017;EMA;4

result expected 
dates;RessourceNameMac;diffsucces
20/02/2017;EMA;4

Comment: Should that be: interval '3 days' ?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: yes, during the last 3 days@Ray O'Donnell

Comment: I add the sample on picture and expected result should be dates;RessourceNameMac;diffsucces 20/02/2017;EMA;4@Gordon Linoff

Comment: hi, the query is still not working..Do you get the poin? Thanks@Gordon Linoff@Ray O'Donnell